# permutation as product of transpositions

Tags: combinatorics

How can the permutation that takes`{-f, -i, i, -e}` into `{-e, -i, i, -f}` be realised as a sequence of nearest neighbour transpositions?
In this case the succession could  be

```
{{-e, i}, {-e, -i}, {-e, -f}, {-i, -f}, {i, -f}}
```

The transposition operation has the following peculiarity: the transposition `{-f, -i}` leaves  `{-f, -i, i, -e}` unchanged since `-f` and `-i` are already in the right order.

I'm interested in the (or a) shortest sequence of transpositions. Often there is more then one shortest sequence.

Comment: I can't make sense of the `{-i, f}` and `{i, f}` swaps since there is not an  `f` element in your original list

Comment: @belisarius Thanks. I will change it to {-i, -f} and {i, -f}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here you have a (rather inefficient) piece of code:

```
l = {a, b, c, d};
r = ReplaceList[Range@Length@l, {a___, x_, y_, b___} -> {a, y, x, b}]; 
g = Quiet@Graph[
    DeleteDuplicates@(Flatten[(UndirectedEdge[x, #] & /@ Function[t, Map[t[[#]] &, r, {2}]][x]) 
    /. x -> # & /@ Permutations@l, 1] /. UndirectedEdge[x_, x_] -> Sequence @@ {}) //.
    {a___, UndirectedEdge[x_, y_], b___, UndirectedEdge[y_, x_], c___} ->
    {a, UndirectedEdge[x, y], b, c}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And now:

```
s = FindShortestPath[g, {a, b, c, d}, {d, b, c, a}]

(*{{a, b, c, d}, {b, a, c, d}, {b, c, a, d}, {b, c, d, a}, {b, d, c, a}, {d, b, c, a}}*)
```

I am **sure** this is the worst possible approach

Now, for finding the transpositions used

```
Partition[s, 2, 1] /. {{a___, b_, c_, d___}, {a___, c_, b_, d___}} -> {b, c}

(*{{a, b}, {a, c}, {a, d}, {c, d}, {b, d}}*)
```

**Edit**

Uglier but much faster

```
swap[l_, j_] := Sequence @@@ {l[[1 ;; j - 1]], l[[j + 1]], l[[j]], l[[j + 2 ;;]]}
w[l_] := Module[{sw, i},
   For[i = 1, i < Length@l, i++,
     sw = swap[l, i];
     If[! MemberQ[k, UndirectedEdge[l, sw]] && ! MemberQ[k, UndirectedEdge[sw, l]],
          AppendTo[k, UndirectedEdge[l, sw]]];
     If[! MemberQ[t, sw], AppendTo[t, sw]; w[sw]]
     ];
   ];
l = {a, b, c, d, e};
k = {};
t = {l};
Block[{$RecursionLimit = 1000}, w[l]];
pg = Graph@k;
s = FindShortestPath[pg, {a, b, c, d, e}, {d, b, e, c, a}]
```

**Edit**

Just boasting, a 3D plot of the permutations:

```
Needs["GraphUtilities`"]
pg3 = GraphPlot3D@g;
coord = GraphCoordinates3D[EdgeList@g /. UndirectedEdge -> Rule];
Thread[VertexList[g] -> coord];
Animate[GraphPlot3D[g, VertexCoordinateRules -> coords, 
  VertexRenderingFunction -> ({Sphere[#1, 0.2]} &), 
  EdgeRenderingFunction -> (Cylinder[#1, 0.1] &), Boxed -> False, 
  ViewPoint -> RotationMatrix[x, {0, 0, 1}].{1.3, -2.4, 2}, 
  SphericalRegion -> True], {x, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/20}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the idea of presenting the permutation group as a graph. Never knew that it is a polyhedron.

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke if you try it with a list of length 5, you'll see how inefficient is this way of generating the group :(

Comment: yeah, also it's more difficult to make it look pleasing embedded in 2 (or 3 projected to 2) dimensions because of the higher edge count per node, but still i like the idea of this isomorphism between permutations and graphs very much!

Comment: @DavidCarraher Congrats on your honorable mention!

Comment: @belisarius Thank you.

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke see edit, please

Comment: @belisarius wow, very nice, thanks for sharing!

Comment: See also, permutahedra :)

Comment: Including other subsets of permutations seems to produce other node transitive graphs :)

Answer (score 10):

This follows the general logic of belisarius' approach.

**Code**

```
h[from_, to_] :=
Module[{f, g, p}, p = Permutations[from, {Length[from]}];
f[list_] := Sort /@ (UndirectedEdge[list, #] & /@ (Permute[ list, Cycles[{#}]] & /@ Partition[Range[Length[list]], 2, 1]));
g = Graph[Flatten[f /@ p, 1] // DeleteDuplicates]; 
FindShortestPath[g, from, to]]
```

**Usage**

```
h[{a, b, c, d}, {d, b, c, a}]
h[{-f, -i, i, -e}, {-e, -i, i, -f}]
h[{leaves, shoots, and, eats}, {eats, shoots, and, leaves}]
```

> {{a, b, c, d}, {a, b, d, c}, {a, d, b, c}, {d, a, b, c}, {d, b, a, 
>     c}, {d, b, c, a}}
>
> {{-f, -i, i, -e}, {-i, -f, i, -e}, {-i, i, -f, -e}, {-i, 
>     i, -e, -f}, {-i, -e, i, -f}, {-e, -i, i, -f}}
>
> {{leaves, shoots, and, eats}, {shoots, leaves, and, eats}, {shoots, 
>     and, leaves, eats}, {shoots, and, eats, leaves}, {shoots, eats, and,
>      leaves}, {eats, shoots, and, leaves}}

Also, just to mix it up...

[image: symbols]

---

**Analysis**

`h[from, to]` finds the shortest path from one node to another. It works with lists of varying lengths (provided that `from` and `to` have the same length).

`f[list]` generates all the edges from the list node. For example

```
f[{a, b, c, d}]
```

[image: edges]

`f /@ Permutations[l, {Length[l]}]` generates the edges for all nodes. `DeleteDuplicates` eliminates repeats.

---

**What swaps were used?**

```
FindPermutation @@@ Partition[{{-f, -i, i, -e}, {-i, -f, i, -e}, {-i, i, -f, -e}, {-i, 
i, -e, -f}, {-i, -e, i, -f}, {-e, -i, i, -f}}, 2, 1]
```

> {Cycles[{{1, 2}}], Cycles[{{2, 3}}], Cycles[{{3, 4}}], 
>    Cycles[{{2, 3}}], Cycles[{{1, 2}}]}

Comment: Very nice! +1 ..

Answer (score 3):

Given a permutation, you can ask Wolfram|Alpha to write it as a product of transpositions. For example: ["transpositions (1,2,4,3,5)"](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=transpositions%20%281,2,4,3,5%29)

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica 7 does not have all the build-in for the graph based approach of belisarius. That is why I tried an other approach

**Code**

```
moveright[list_List, i_Integer, j_Integer] := Module[{},
  Table[{list[[k + 1]], list[[i]]}, {k, i, j - 1}]
  ]

transpositions[from_List, to_List] := Module[{now = from, next , i, transp List[]},
  For[i = Length[from], i > 1, i--,
   next = DeleteCases[now, to[[i]]]~Append~to[[i]];
   transp = Join[transp, moveright[now, Position[now, to[[i]], 1][[1, 1]], i]];
   now = Drop[next, -1];
  ];
 transp
]

 transpositions[{a, b, c, d}, {a, d, c, b}]
```

results in a sequence of transpositions that maps `{a, b, c, d}` to `{a, d, c, b}`:

```
 {{c, b}, {d, b}, {d, c}}
```

**Explanation**

If we want to go from `{a, b, c, d}` to `{a, d, c, b}`, we could

1. First look at the most right element of the final sequence, b. Why not move it to the end, thus from position 2 to position 4. The intermediate state is `{a, c, d, b}` .
2. Next we look at the second element from the right of the final sequence, c. In the intermediate result,  c is at position 2. We move it to position 3 where it must eventually be.
   The intermediate state is `{a, d, c, b}` .
3. The third element from the right is already in the right place.
4. The last element must automatically be in the right position

This is a function generates the movements:

```
transpositions[from_List, to_List] := 
Module[{now = from, next , i, transp},
 For[i = Length[from], i > 1, i--,
  next = Complement[now, {to[[i]]}]~Append~to[[i]];
  Print[moveright[now, Position[now, to[[i]]][[1, 1]], i]];
  now = Drop[next, -1];
  ]
 ]

transpositions[{a, b, c, d}, {a, d, c, b}]
```

it gives

```
moveright[{a,b,c,d},2,4]   
moveright[{a,c,d},2,3]
moveright[{a,d},2,2]
```

`moveright[{a,b,c,d},2,4]` is to be interpreted as: move element 2 of `{a,b,c,d}` to position 4.

Notice that the intermediate steps become shorter at each step. The last elements of the intermediate step are already in final position, and no other element will be moved to the right of them. They will not participate in any movement any more, so they can be dropped.

At last we need a way to move elements to the right. The only operation avaiable is to swapping two neibouring elments.

```
moveright[list_List, i_Integer, j_Integer] := Module[{},
  Table[{list[[k + 1]], list[[i]]}, {k, i, j - 1}]
  ]
 moveright[{a, b, c, d}, 2, 4]
```

results in a sequence of two transpositions that bring '{a, b, c, d}' to '{a, c, d, b}'

```
{{c, b}, {d, b}}
```